# Visualizer for serial port activity (for sent and received data)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serial-port

My application actively uses a serial port for interactive communication with a device. What I need is to add some kind of visualizer of sending and receiving data from the serial port (two blinking lights similar to two blinking computers for the network activity in the system tray). 
What approach should I follow to implement this functionality properly?

Comment: What are you doing so far?  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35775-serial-port-communication-in-c%23/ is a good starter to serialport, normally you would listen for DataReceived for incoming data.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to create a StatusStrip, and add a section dedicated for these indicators. Next, pick out the images for individual states and set the appropriate one every time you have activity. Here is some rough code.

```
private System.Drawing.Image StateImageX { get; set; }
private System.Drawing.Image StateImageY { get; set; }

public delegate void DelegateRefreshControls ();
public DelegateRefreshControls RefreshControlHandler;

public Form1 ()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.StateImageX = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"??\ImageX.png");
    this.StateImageY = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"??\ImageY.png");

    this.RefreshControlHandler += new DelegateRefreshControls(this.RefreshControls);
}

private void Form1_FormClosing (object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.RefreshControlHandler -= new DelegateRefreshControls(this.RefreshControls);
}

private void SerialPort_Activity (object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(this.RefreshControlHandler);
}

public void RefreshControls ()
{
    if (state == x) this.ToolStripStatusLabel.Image = this.StateImageX;
    if (state == y) this.ToolStripStatusLabel.Image = this.StateImageY;
}
```